# How to trigger change event on HTML input programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

I am trying to populate a HTML input programmatically inside a WKWebView and it looks like it is not triggering the normal events. For example, when I try to programmatically populate the input field inside the "google.com" page, the results popup is not presented.
The input field is populated correctly, the submit works as expected, but the results popup does not appear while "typing".
Is this a limitation of the system?

This is how I run my javascript code on the active element.

```
let script = """
        var input = document.activeElement;
        input.value = '\(text)';
        var event = new Event('input');
        input.dispatchEvent(event);
        """
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { result, error in
            // 
        }
```

Comment: Have you verified that Google's implementation on their site is based on subscribing to the `input` event specifically, in the first place ...? If that is not the case, and they used something else - then you can go and trigger `input` events all day long, with nobody caring about it.